# Fixing porcelain sink with crack and rusting drain

Tags: plumbing, sink

Is there a way for me to fix this sink that has a crack and a rusting drain without replacing the sink?

The vanity is built around the sink. I don't know if I can get a similar sink and I don't want to touch the custom built vanity.

[image: sink wide shot]
[image: sink close up]

Comment: If by "fix" you mean "replace the sink and vanity" Or "replace the sink and rebuild the vanity around the new sink" yes. Otherwise, no, in any meaningful fashion, but you can attempt something with epoxy that will ultimately be unsatisfying unless you have very low standards for being satisfied. The rusty drain should be able to be removed and replaced, the crack is the fundamental problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just updated the post to be clearer.  I would like to fix the existing sink in the best way if possible. Or as you say, the only way won't be cosmetically pleasing.

Comment: depending one the level of perfection you are after you might install a new drain. Clean up the rust while its out. Apply porcelain touch up paint to the crack. (I'm assuming the crack is in the surface and not a leak)

Answer (score 1):

Look on the market for plastic covering: you'll only have to replace the drain and seal the new plastic 'sink-in-sink' over the existing sink. I find them often for bathtubs but exists also for sinks.

Answer (score 0):

buy a new sink. it is like $100

Comment: sure but good luck finding one to fit that vanity..  ( actually i suppose its a free standing sink with the vanity built around it )

Comment: This vanity and sink may be more than 50 years old. I may not find one that fit it exactly.